# Non-system Tables appear as Master Database Tables in SQL Server 2017 Dev

Tags: database, sql-server, master

After trying to install AdventureWorks ( run it, query it against the Master database)unsuccessfully a few times,  I have somehow ended up with many of the AdventureWorks tables somehow ending up as part of the Master Database of the Default instance; please see attached, the middle-left part. I am clueless on what to do. Please suggest something:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the case that one of your attempts ended up with you executing the `create table` commands when connected to the master database (which is probably the default database for the user you're logging in with - I've been there myself, not a good practice though). I'm gonna list a few options:

- **1st - Just drop the extra tables**

You only added some user tables to the master database, therefore no harm would come if you just dropped them. If you didn't install any kind of third party software or scripts on your SQL Server 2017 Dev, you can [drop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) all those user tables from the **Tables** folder with no worry of breaking something. But don't drop objects from the subfolders.

If you connect to the master database and query `sys.objects`, you should be able to list all the tables you created:

```
USE master;
GO

SELECT name, type_desc, create_date, is_ms_shipped 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type = 'U'
    AND is_ms_shipped = 0;
GO
```

You could also check the names of the tables on AdventureWorks when you finish installing it properly to be sure that you only drop the correspondent ones from master database.

- **2nd - Restore from a backup (if you happened to have one available)**

Since [master](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database?view=sql-server-2017) database is a really important  database that could even cause your SQL Server not to start, microsoft provided documentation on how to [Restore the master Database (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-the-master-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in case you have it corrupted or something alike.

- **3rd - Rebuild from the template**

You could follow the documentation on how to [Rebuild System Databases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017). There's a disadvantage on using this method though: it will be like a factory restore of master, model, msdb, and tempdb system databases.